# Steam expansion for non-Steam game

Tags: steam, victoria-2

In 2014 I bought Victoria II and in 2015 its 'A House Divided' expansion using a site called "Gamesrocket". I can't add the license keys to my Steam account, so I'm guessing they're either expired or just can't be added to Steam. Now I want to add the 'Heart of Iron' expansion to it, and start with a clean install.

I've reached out to Gamesrocket to renew my download links (I messed with the files for modding before I learned how to do proper modding). The first one didn't work but I'm still in contact with them about it.

Now I'd like to know:

- will it give issues when trying to add a Steam-bought game expansion ('Heart of Iron') on top of my non-Steam bought versions (the base game and 'A House Divided' expansion)?
- Or should I just buy all three from Steam again as mixing those would cause strange errors?

Comment: I'd say errors would be more probable. Don't think Steam would allow something like that.

Comment: yeah that's what I fear too sad as it's all legal bought versions. As far as I know if you buy from gamesrocket nowadays you get a steam code but apparently back then they didn't.

Comment: Hi NarmerTheLion, I have edited your post, and hopefully interpreted it right (the base game and AHD expansion being non-steam). If not, please feel free to change it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it will give issues.**
Even if you are able to buy DLC through Steam of a base game you don't own on the platform - which is likely impossible - installing it properly would be difficult and cumbersome, if at all viable (different files, different structures, different registry entries, &c.).

The game is currently on [sale](https://store.steampowered.com/app/42960/Victoria_II/) on Steam, though (75% off).

Comment: yes I noticed it being on sale which is why I decided to suddenly throw in the question but then I'll consider buying the whole package again from steam directly and resolve all issues